# Evaluating the Heapsort algorithm

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have to evaluate the complexity of the following [HeapSort algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhIMw.jpg)  (actually procedure "HeapSort").
Procedure **fixHeap** makes log(n) operations. In **constructHeap** it will be done r=n/2 times. So, we have log(n)*n/2 for first line.
Next we will call **fixHeap** n-1 times, so (n-1)*log(n).
And in the end we have log(n) * n/2 + log(n) * (n-1) = log(n) * (1,5*n - 1) ?

Am I right in this way or not? If not, tell me please how to evaluate this correctly. Thank you.

A - array, n - number of elements

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Seems like a straightforward algorithm to me.  Use $n$ insertions to construct the heap, each insertion requires $\log n$ time.  Use $n$ removals of the largest element to construct the sorted list.  Each removal requires $\log n$ time.